# select records with multi key list

Tags: mysql

hi I have a list of primary keys of other tables in my field k in table A like this :

```
    id=1 and ref=2 and fun=1
    id=1 and ref=5 and fun=2
    id=2 and ref=1 and fun=1
```

and I have a table B which it's primary key is id,ref,fun

now I want to select all records from table B where primary key matches the values in table A
,
of course the

```
    select * from B where A.k
```

.. works
but get one record by one select

I ask for select all records from table B that matches A.k in table A.

thank you in advance.

Comment: MySQL won't interpret a string column as an expression to evaluate.

Comment: when the A.kk content is a string like 'id=1 and ref=2 and fun=1' you can do select something from B where .. the value of a.k is the string above

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will not treat the value of `A.k` as an expression to re-evaluate -- it's not substituted into the SQL and executed recursively. When you write `WHERE A.k`, it simply tests whether the contents of the `k` column is true or false.

You shouldn't put all the values in a single column. You should have separate columns for `id`, `ref`, and `fun` in table A. Then you can join the tables:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM B
JOIN A ON B.id = A.id AND B.ref = A.ref AND B.fun = A.fun
```

If you really want to have SQL expressions in a table column, you'll need to create dynamic SQL in a stored procedure.

```
SET @where = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', k, ')') SEPARATOR ' OR ')
              FROM A);
PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT * FROM B WHERE ', @where);
EXECUTE stmt;
```

See the MySQL documentation on [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)